# Using own decorators with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, decorator, conftest

I would like to use a "helper" decorator in multiple pytest test files:

```
min311 = pytest.mark.skipif(sys.version_info < (3,11), reason="You need at least Python v3.11 to run this test")

...
@min311
def test_...
```

Which is the best place for `min311`? It is not imported automatically from `conftest.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Given this layout:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── mycode
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── main.py
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_mycode.py

4 directories, 6 files
```

If I define `min311` in `tests/conftest.py`, then in `test_mycode.py` I can write:

```
from tests.conftest import min311

@min311
def test_something():
  ...
```

This assumes that we are running `pytest` from the top-level directory.

This also works for the simpler layout:

```
.
├── conftest.py
├── mycode
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_mycode.py
```

---

If you don't want to import from `conftest` directly, just move the decorator definition somewhere more palatable. I've seen a number of projects that include something like a `test_helpers` module in their code:

```
.
├── conftest.py
├── mycode
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── test_helpers.py
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    └── test_mycode.py
```

Then you can:

```
from mycode.test_helpers import min311
```

Comment: Yes, I can import conftest directly, but I found multiple counter-recommendations to import conftest explicitely into test files.